# wordpress, trying to get white div superimposed on black body

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I can do something in simple html/css, which is set the  to a black background and have a white  centered in front of it, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body
{
  background-color:#000;
}


#div1
{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:90%;
  background-color:#eeeeee;
}

#bannerImg
{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <img id="bannerImg" src="brav-banner-3.jpg">
    <p>This is some text.
    <p> And some more.
    <p> And some more.
  </div>
</body>
```

But when I try the same thing in WordPress, using the BlankSlate theme, I can't get any white to show. Here is header.php, front-page.php, and style.css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
   <head>
     ....
   </head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
   <div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
      <header id="header" role="banner">
         <img src="<?php get_template_directory()?>/assets/img/brav-banner-3.jpg">
         <div id="navDiv"><nav id="menu" role="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
         </nav></div>
      </header>
   <div id="container">
```

front-page.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section id="content" role="main">
  <div id="info">
       <h4>In the Los Angeles area? </h4> <p>Ask about free demo loaners! </p>
       <h4>We also take mail orders.</h4> On all orders, there is a 30-day return policy!</p> 
  </div>
  <div id="longSlogan">
       <img class="frontpageimg" src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/assets/img/slogan-2.jpg">

  </div>
</section>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

style.css:

```
#header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:90%;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

#longSlogan {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#container {
  clear:both;
  backgroud-color:#fff;
}

nav {
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Adding the white color in div 'content' instead of container would probably help.

Comment: I suspected it was actually primarily a css issue because in this case WordPress is doing nothing behind the scenes, and sure enough Marijke's suggestion worked. Has something to do with css behavior.